# TestNg @afterclass isn't invoked if there is disabled test in a class

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I am using testng+webdriver for automated testing. And have a problem that @AfterClass annotation doesn't work as I expected.

I have following test class:

```
    public class WorkspaceTest{
        @BeforeClass
        public void init(){
            //Initialization steps
        }

        @Test
        public void testMethod1{...}

        @Test
        public void testMethod2{...}

        @Test(enabled=false)
        public void testMethod3{...}

        @AfterClass(alwaysRun=true)
        public void tearDown{
            //finalizing steps 
        }
```

}

If all test methods are enabled - tearDown method works fine,
but if one of tests is disabled  - I even don't reach break point in tearDown method.

Is it expected behavior for `@AfterClass` annotation? or I do something wrong?

```
Testng version: 6.1.1
Webdriver 2.5.0
Java 1.6.0_26
```

Comment: I ran into the same bug when I ran the TestNG test in IntelliJ, but it called the `@AfterClass` correctly (even when one method was `enabled=false`) when I ran the test via Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
tearDown
PASSED: testMethod1
PASSED: testMethod2

===============================================
    Test1
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Here is the source I used:

```
public class A {
      @BeforeClass
      public void init(){
          //Initialization steps
      }

      @Test
      public void testMethod1() {}

      @Test
      public void testMethod2() {}

      @Test(enabled=false)
      public void testMethod3() {}

      @AfterClass(alwaysRun=true)
      public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("tearDown");
      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! Looks like I localized the problem. There is some issues with Eclipse testng plugin. The same test is working fine on IntelliJIdea

Comment: Can you email the testng-users list with your findings? Happy to take a look to find out if it's a problem with the TestNG Eclipse plug-in.

Answer (score -2):

If you using standard junit @AfterClass should be annotated on public static void method, for example:

```
@AfterClass
public static void logout() {}
```